# Can android give force close without throwing an exception?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-logcat, forceclose

I have a force close error in my code somewhere... I have wrapped the whole of `onCreate()` in a try catch block to see what it is... but this is not catching it?

Is it possible that a force close can occur without throwing an exception object?

Thanks.

Comment: It may happen before the onCreate method. if you post your code, and maybe the manifest XML, it'll be easier to all of us.

Comment: Yes, on low memory, for example. But what types of exception are you trying to catch? Can you show onCreate() method?

Comment: Show us the LogCat error. I'm going to guess you haven't declared the Activity that your trying to start in your Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible. Are you working in eclipse? Review logcat (post the log?) and see - or you could put a breakpoint near where you suspect it might be crashing and watch what happens step-by-step using debug.

If you're in some other IDE, try something like bugsense and see what it reports.

Comment: I agree Hiverzz. It's not possible that at force close occur without throwing an exception object. But this exception could be never handled by your app or - in your case - in the `onCreate()` method.